# Where can I promote my SDK for Android

Tags: android, localization, language-translation

I have created a [library](https://www.stringx.io) for automatic translation. Where can I promote it. Do you know any pages/forums for that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not relate to programming.

Comment: Stack is not only for stricte programming issues.

Comment: Yes, it is, actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Android Arsenal: https://android-arsenal.com/

For reference I got about 60 GitHub stars in a few days from here.

Comment: @SzymonKlimaszewski Also check out the other library sites listed at the bottom of the wiki page: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info